# Parsing _utmz cookie substrings to Google Tag Manager variables

Tags: javascript, regex, cookies, google-tag-manager

I'm attempting to set custom javascript variables in Google Tag Manager to be the utmcsr, utmccn, utmcmd, and utmctr portions of Google's legacy analytics _utmz cookie.

The _utmz cookie looks like this:

```
utmz=123456789.1234567890.1.1.utmcsr=[Source]|utmgclid=[ad click id]|utmccn=[campaign]|utmcmd[medium]|utmctr=[keyword]
```

I'm not great at JavaScript or Regex, but here's the closest I've gotten where GTM doesn't give me a token error. I grabbed this bit from another website and attempted to modify to grab the utmcsr.

```
function() {
 var __utmzCookie = document.cookie.match(/utmcsr=(.*)/);
 if(__utmzCookie && __utmzCookie[1]) {
   var utmzVals = __utmzCookie[1].split('.');
   if(utmzVals[2]) {
     return utmzVals[1] + '.' + utmzVals[2];
   }
 }
}
```

Comment: To note, the above function is returning the utmctr substring.

Comment: Is there a typo in your example ? Shouldn't there be a pipe character before utmsrc instead of a dot (IIRC the utm values are all separated by pipes, but I haven't looked at the old GA cookies for quite some time).